# Let $x$, $y$, $z$, $t$ are real numbers. $x+y+z+t=6$ and $\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{4-y^2}+\sqrt{9-z^2}+\sqrt{16-t^2}=8$ Find each value of them as a number.

Tags: vectors, systems-of-equations, radicals, real-numbers, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

It's so hard. How do you find it? It's just two equations but four variables. Can someone help me?

Comment: one solution is $(x,y,z,t) = \frac35 \times (1,2,3,4)$.

Comment: Try not to just post questions, as people won't know where to start to be able to help you (and you will get downvotes and close votes, as has happened here). Try to explain what you have tried and where and why you got stuck/need help. It would also help if you said where you found this question (week X of course Y, where we covered topic Z).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider following 4 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$,
$$\vec{a} = (x,\sqrt{1-x^2}),\;\;
\vec{b} = (y,\sqrt{4-y^2}),\;\;
\vec{c} = (z,\sqrt{9-z^2})\;\;\text{ and }\;\;
\vec{d} = (t,\sqrt{16-t^2})
$$
We have $|\vec{a}| = 1, |\vec{b}| = 2, |\vec{c}| = 3$ and $|\vec{d}| = 4$.
The given conditions tell us
$$\vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} + \vec{d} = (6,8)\\
\implies
|\vec{a} + \vec{b} + \vec{c} + \vec{d}| = |(6,8)| = 10 = |\vec{a}| + |\vec{b}| + |\vec{c}| + |\vec{d}|
$$
By triangle inequality, this is possible only when the 4 vectors are pointing in same direction. This implies
$$x : y : z : t = |\vec{a}| : |\vec{b}| : |\vec{c}| : |\vec{d}| = 1 : 2 : 3 : 4 \\
\implies (x,y,z,t) = \left(\frac{3}{5}, \frac{6}{5}, \frac{9}{5}, \frac{12}{5}\right)
$$

Comment: Hat down! Genious!

Comment: $b$ should be $(y, \sqrt{4-y^2})$

Comment: @user58697 fixed, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM
$$8=\sqrt{(1-x)(1+x)}+\sqrt{(2-y)(2+y)}+\sqrt{(3-z)(3+z)}+\sqrt{(4-t)(4+t)}=$$
$$=2\sqrt{(1-x)\cdot\frac{1+x}{4}}+2\sqrt{(2-y)\cdot\frac{2+y}{4}}+2\sqrt{(3-z)\cdot\frac{3+z}{4}}+2\sqrt{(4-t)\cdot\frac{4+t}{4}}\leq$$
$$\leq1-x+\frac{1+x}{4}+2-y+\frac{2+y}{4}+3-z+\frac{3+z}{4}+4-t+\frac{4+t}{4}=8,$$
which gives
$$1-x=\frac{1+x}{4},$$
$$2-y=\frac{2+y}{4},$$ 
$$3-z=\frac{3+z}{4}$$ and
$$4-t=\frac{4+t}{4}$$ or
$$(x,y,z,t)=\left(\frac{3}{5},\frac{6}{5},\frac{9}{5},\frac{12}{5}\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

[image]Hint: Think in a plane coordinates, $x,y,z,t$ can be placed consecutively on the $x$-axis, while $\sqrt{1-x^2},\dots$ can be placed consecutively on the $y$-axis.